# How to start activity from CallScreeningService in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the application that this CallScreeningService is written in open when the incoming phone number matches certain numbers. In this case the if statement in onScreenCall calls runs but the Activity isn't started. I'm not sure why, I'm guessing it's because I don't have the right context of the application. Does anyone know how I would get the correct context or what i'm doing wrong here?

```
public class CallScreenService extends CallScreeningService {
Context nContext = this; 

@Override
public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {

   if (callDetails.getHandle().toString().equals("tel:333333333")) {

        Intent i = new Intent(nContext, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        nContext.startActivity(i);
    
   } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The app needs to have granted SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission by the user on Android 10+.

You have to add it in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And to request it from user:

```
// Show alert dialog to the user saying a separate permission is needed
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
startActivity(myIntent);
```